# Is It Possible to Make Every Instance of a Word on a Website Non-Breaking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

We have a hyphenated word that we use frequently on our website and we never want it to wrap or break - we always want the two parts of the word on the same line.

Is there a way to make every instance of this word on the site non-breaking or do I have to do it with something like `"white-space: nowrap"` in a span around every instance of the word?

Ideally, would love to be able to do an update where every instance of the word that exists on the site becomes non-breaking, without having to manually go and update each word.

Thanks!

Comment: You could wrap each instance of the word in a `span` and give a class like `no-break` then have the css `.no-break{ white-space: nowrap;}`

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) `&nbsp;`, look into the non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`:

```
Hello&#8209;World
```

This will render as `Hello‑World`, however it won't be broken up in two lines.

Comment: Thanks @timo! That would apply it to every new instance of the word but is there a way to apply it to every instance that already exists on the site? Updated the original question to be more clear.

Comment: Depending on how your page is built, Ctrl+F & replace or a database conversion. You probably shouldn't do this at runtime in the browser.

Comment: Hmm ok might have to play around with a find / replace in the database and see if that will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## The fastest way

The [fastest](https://jsperf.com/createnodeiterator-vs-createtreewalker-vs-getelementsby) way to replace some text globally on a website is to walk through only text nodes inside a DOM tree.

You can achieve that by using `document.createTreeWalker` and then replacing only text nodes containing the word (or character) you want to change.

```js
var findAndReplaceText = function(el, from, to) {
  if (!el || !from || !to) {
    return;
  }

  var node, nodes = [];
  var walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

  // Find nodes
  while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
    if (from instanceof RegExp) {
      from.test(node.wholeText) && nodes.push(node);
    } else {
      node.wholeText.indexOf(from) !== -1 && nodes.push(node);
    }
  }

  // Change DOM
  while (nodes.length > 0) {
    //nodes[0].replaceWith(
    //  document.createTextNode(nodes[0].wholeText.replace(from, to))
    //);
    nodes[0].textContent = nodes[0].wholeText.replace(from, to)
    nodes.splice(0, 1);
  }
};

findAndReplaceText(document.getElementById('fake-hyphens'), /[\u002d\u2010]/g, '\u2011');
findAndReplaceText(document.documentElement, 'lol', 'non');

// \u2010 - hypen
// \u2011 - non-breakable hyphen
// \u002d - minus
```

```css
section {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

section p {
  width: 200px;
  outline: dashed red 1px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="fake-hyphens">
  <header>Replace to lol-breakable hyphens</header>
  <p>one-half mother-in-law eighty-six one-third merry-go-round well-being mass-produced over-the-counter daughter-in-law merry-go-round</p>
</section>

<section>
  <header>Without replacement for comparison</header>
  <p>one-half mother-in-law eighty-six one-third merry-go-round well-being mass-produced over-the-counter daughter-in-law merry-go-round</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe mentioned, you can loop through your content and use regex to identify and replace your word with a `span` that applies `white-space: nowrap`

Here's a demo using jquery.

```js
var keyword = 'some-word',
    re = new RegExp(keyword,"g");

$('p').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(re, '<span class="nowrap">'+keyword+'</span>'))
});
```

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words</p>
<p>these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words</p>
<p>these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words these are words and this is some-word and here are more words</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that recursively changes hyphens to non-breaking hyphens for all text nodes:

```js
function changeHyphens(element) {
  var nodes = element.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === 1) { //this is an element node
      changeHyphens(nodes[i]);
    } else if (nodes[i].nodeType === 3) { //this is a text node
      nodes[i].nodeValue = nodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/-/g, '\u2011');
    }
  }
} //changeNodes

changeHyphens(document.body);
```

```html
<p>
  this-is-a-test this-is-a-longer-test this-is-a-longest-test-that-should-not-break this-is-a-test this-is-a-longer-test this-is-a-test-that-should-not-break this-is-a-test this-is-a-longer-test this-is-a-longest-test-that-should-not-break this-is-a-test
  this-is-a-longer-test this-is-a-test-that-should-not-break
</p>
```